# bootstrap callback validator in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I want to use bootstrap [callback validator](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/validators/callback/) for date range validation in my project on angularjs. All works fine when the callback function is simple javascript function. But I need to call function from angular controller to get data from the scope. 
How can I do such a thing?

**View:**

```
        <div class="form-group inputGroupContainer" ng-controller="DatepickerCtrl">
            <label for="date">Date of Birth</label>
            <p class="input-group">
                <input type="text" name="date1" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" class="form-control"
                       ui-date="{dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}" ui-date-format="dd/MM/yyyy" datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
                       ng-model="user.Personal.BirthDate"
                       data-bv-callback="true"
                       data-bv-callback-message="Invalid date"
                       data-bv-callback-callback={{checkBirthDate}}
                       is-open="opened" close-text="Close" />
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                </span>
            </p>
        </div>
```

**Function in angular's controller (not working)**:

```
$scope.checkBirthDate = function () {
        return moment($scope.user.Personal.BirthDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).isBefore(new Date());
       };
```

**Callback function in javascript (works fine)**:

```
function checkBirthDate(value, validator) {
    return moment(value, 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).isBefore(new Date());
};
```

Comment: Something like this

data-bv-callback-callback="angular.element(this).scope().checkBirthDate(this)"

Comment: error - "angular.element(this) is not defined"

Comment: i think you can not do it // IMPORTANT NOTICE: You have to declare the callback as a global function
// outside of $(document).ready()